# Visual Studio not showing the .NET CORE projects

Tags: .net-framework

Dev Env details: Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9, Windows 10.0

I installed a new version of .NET core (2.2.203) recently.

I have some older versions as well in my machine. But I was not able to view the any of the .NET core version in the target version of .netcore project. It was only displaying .NET frameworks.

So I cleaned most of the old version, but now after that Visual Studio not even showing the .net core projects.

When a new .net core project is created I can only view the solution with 0 projects.

I have even tried installing vs 2019 but I can see the same behavior there.

I also tried repairing and uninstalling and reinstalling VS2017 with no success. As both of the VS 2017 and 2019 showing the same behavior, I guess something is wrong with the .net core installation.

I can test a console application from .net core cmd and it is working.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by the following step.

1. Uninstalled all the versions of .dotnet sdk and runtime installations from pgms and features
2. Also run the following power shell script to double check the instillation process. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScriptsToRemoveOldNETCoreSDKs.aspx

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -match "Microsoft .NET Core SDK"
}

Write-Host $app.Name 
Write-Host $app.IdentifyingNumber
pushd $env:SYSTEMROOT\System32

$app.identifyingnumber |% { Start-Process msiexec -wait -ArgumentList "/x $_" }

popd
```

3. Delete dotnet folder from C:\Program Files
4. Restart  the machine.Verify in ctrlpanel>progmsnfeatures  there is no .dotnet core [runtime/sdk]installations
5. From ctrlpanel>progmsnfeatures >open visual studio 2017 for modification ,uncheck the .net core and click Modify and then again check it and click Modify.Restart machine.
6. Open a new .net core project. Now you will be able see the projects under the solution.